# Exporting images day by day in a short way

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to export the Sentinel 5p images day by day. I don't know very well the GEE. I found how can plot the day of year chart but i also need the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Export.image.to function. If you have enough Google Drive capacity you should use Export.image.toDrive(). This will export a .tiff to your Google Drive.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image,
  description: 'this_is_my_image',
  scale: 30,
  region: roi
});
```

Comment: Thank you ALO! I know this code but i didn't find out how i can download the satellite images per day easily. I mean, for each day, i don't want to change the startdate and enddate codes all the time. There must be an easier way. I don't know that i have explained myself clearly.